# How to ignore transparency when using ffmpeg with PNG files?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding, png, transparency

Every topic I find shows how to keep the transparency but I want to remove it without having to change the image format.

Camtasia is crashing when I import the ffmpeg encoded MP4 file using the PNG files. The advice was to use a video format without transparency.

Comment: Convert them to 24-bit png instead of 32-bit, transparency will be discarded. You didn't say what platform you're on but there are a million image conversion apps out there for all platforms.

Comment: Thanks, Windows. Somehow if I change CRF from 0 to 1 it worked.

Comment: Converting PNG to MP4 (assuming via encoder libx264) will automatically remove transparency. Need to at least see your command to make any suggestions.